# How do I specify the namespace of an xml file targeted by an xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

If I had an XML file that specifies a namespace, such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>Manager</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.something.ManagerBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <ejb-local-ref>
                <ejb-ref-name>Manager</ejb-ref-name>
                <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
                <local-home>com.something.ManagerLocalHome</local-home>
                <local>com.something.ManagerLocal</local>
                <ejb-link>Manager</ejb-link>
            </ejb-local-ref>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

And I wanted to extract just the names with an XSLT, for example,

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                version="1.0"
>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/ejb-jar/enterprise-beans/session">
        <session>
            <xsl:value-of select="ejb-name"/>
        </session>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am I missing?  This transform seems to work if I remove the source's `xmlns` - how can I leave it on and still run the transform?

I was expecting something like:

```
<session>
  Manager
</session>
<session>
  Manager2
</session>
...
```

(Really just trying to figure out the namespace issue)

Comment: Please show desired output. It is not clear what you mean by *extract just the names*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need return of the *ejb-name* and *ejb-ref-name* elements, consider adding a namespace prefix like *doc* to your XSLT to use as reference to elements. The XPath `descendant::*` is used to find names however nested from *session*.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:doc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                exclude-result-prefixes="doc"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/doc:ejb-jar/doc:enterprise-beans">
        <session>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:session"/>
        </session>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:session">
        <name><xsl:value-of select="descendant::doc:ejb-name"/></name>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="descendant::doc:ejb-ref-name"/></name>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<session>
  <name>Manager</name>
  <name>Manager</name>
</session>
```

[XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzW)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  Essentially, I have to declare the namespace in the XSLT, then prefix all the nodes I'm searching for.  Is there a way to control the output namespace?  For example, if I throw in a copy-of, it necessitates a separation of namespaces between the written tags (`<name>`) and the copied elements - I'd like to keep it homogeneous.

Comment: We are not declaring a namespace but only assigning a namespace prefix used only to reference the elements. Same process as XPath. Your example is not clear to me. Can you rephrase?